Could not create virtual pointer (virtual pointer unsupported?)
I'm trying to run an app called Warpd on Ubuntu, but I'm encountering an error. Interestingly, when I use the 'sudo' command, it works. However, I'd like to know how I can run the app without having to resort to 'sudo' all the time, as 'sudo' only works in the terminal. I want to be able to run the app on GUI.

(1) Is this the app you are talking about?  (2) Please don’t post images of text, for various reasons; see: PSA: Please don’t post images of text.  Instead, copy the text and paste it here as a code block.  (E.g., use “code fences” — see Markdown Editing Help and click on “show more”.)  ... (Cont’d)

(Cont’d) …  (3) Your image doesn’t even illustrate your question. Does sudo warpd --grid work?

Yes, it works when i use sudo
